# Theta time complexity of a recursive function

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Finding the Theta order runtime of the following snippet of code is giving me trouble:

```
void foo(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
    }

    foo(n / 2);
    foo(n / 2);
}
```

The `if` statement is Θ(1). The `for` loop is Θ(n). It seems to me that the recursive function calls are Θ(log n). My understanding is that I would add up the Thetas, and the highest order (Θ(n)) would survive, and the segment of code is order Θ(n). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `foo` is  Θ(f(n)) for some function `f`. What changes is the size of `n` for each recursive call. You need to solve the equation `f(n) = Θ(n) + 2f(n/2)` for `f`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, here is a proper explanation of what is going on. The time complexity is
`Θ(n log n)`.

---

The **first** thing to notice is that we are working with a *nested loop*. (Recursion is another way of writing a loop.)

This means that our complexity function will look something like `n`×`k`. For convenience, we will treat `n` as *number of elements* and `k` as *recursion depth*. Let’s draw an example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  ← number of elements
---------------  1st pass
------- -------  2nd pass
--- --- --- ---  3rd pass
- - - - - - - -  4th pass ← recursion depth
```

---

The **second** thing to notice is that *every* element of your array is touched every time the function is called. We touch all `n` the first pass. Then we recurse for `n/2` and `n/2`, but again all `n` are touched. Repeat for each level of recursion — *all* `n` are touched.¹

<sup>¹ Almost. Try drawing an example for 10 elements. You will see that some elements are not touched in the *final* pass. Don’t let this bother you... we’ll revisit the *why* in a moment.</sup>

---

The **third** thing to notice is that the *recursion depth* is different than the number of elements. That is, `k`≠`n`!

You might at first think 8 : 4 → one half, but try drawing an example with, say, 16 elements: we find that the ratio is now 16 : 4 → one quarter. How about 12 elements? 12 : 4 (one *third?*). How about 17–32 elements? Yep: 17–32 : 5 (wut?).

You should instantly recognize this as a *logarithmic* progression base 2. (Remember, a logarithm is the mathematical inverse of exponentiation.) The original function has a logarithmic *base* of `2` (because we invoke recursion twice each time, once over each half of the current section of the array). It is logarithmic because it shrinks our recursion depth instead of increasing it.

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ⌈log<sub>2</sub> 8⌉ → | ⌈3⌉ → | 3 |  | 2³ = 8 |
| ⌈log<sub>2</sub> 10⌉ → | ⌈3.32⌉ → | 4 |  | 2³⋅³² = 10 |
| ⌈log<sub>2</sub> 12⌉ → | ⌈3.58⌉ → | 4 |  | ... |
| ⌈log<sub>2</sub> 16⌉ → | ⌈4⌉ → | 4 |  | ... |

It is a *ceiling* function because recursion depth is an integer. (You cannot *kind of* recurse, sort of. You either did or didn’t.)²

Thus, `k`=`log₂n`.

<sup>² This is the second piece of the puzzle about why we don’t care about the final pass not being perfect... we’re still not done yet, though.</sup>

---

We can put it together now. Our complexity function is `f(n) → n log₂n`.

Since the algorithm runs the same in the *worst* case (`O(n log n)`) and in the *best* case (`Ω(n log n)`), we now also have a tight bound for it: `Θ(n log n)`.

Complexity notation throws out stuff that doesn’t matter. We do not care if the *actual* complexity is something like `n + 2` because as `n` gets larger (“goes toward infinity”, or for us programmers, goes to several hundred thousand) that +2 is meaningless, as is whether or not we actually get through all `n` elements on the very last pass.³

It is the same reason that we can toss out the base on the logarithm. It ultimately doesn’t matter. All you need is the term with the highest power and you are good enough. For example, `O(2n² + 4n - 3)` → `O(n²)` because the larger `n` gets the more that `n²` dominates the whole thing.

<sup>³ Hah, got there!</sup>

---

---

A lot of this stuff requires *familiarity* with it.
We can also see that even experienced developers who haven’t thought these thoughts in a while (and when especially sleep-deprived) can make really, really dumb mistakes, as I did when I first answered with a blithe O(n²).

Sorry it took so long to think about how I wanted to word this for y’all. Thinking about these things does get a little easier with time (and constant *repetition*, lol).

Comment: I see what you mean; Thanks! Also, the function can just be considered a "loop," correct? Because it is, as you put it, "Going through N values," and "Repeating for N values": the Big-Θ would just be Θ(n) * Θ(n) = Θ(n^2) ("outer loop" times "inner loop").

Comment: Yes. All complexity calculations boil down to counting nested loops. (And recursion is just another way to write a loop.)

Comment: The recursion depth is only `Theta(log(N))`. It can be seen that all calls with the same depth combined always iterate the loop `Theta(N)` times in sum. So the overall time is `Theta(N log N)`.

Comment: oooop! yeah, uh, I should really get some sleep. Hey, OP, user17732522 is right, and I goofed a really, _really_ easy answer. @user17732522 you should make an answer that shows the correct way. I’ll delete mine in an hour or two. If you don’t wanna, I’ll update mine with the correct recursion depth thinking.